# security warning in IE9 "Show all content"

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I'm implementing the [facebook Comments plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) on my site. Users get the warning "Show all content" in IE9

[This other publisher](http://www.vg.no/teknologi/artikkel.php?artid=10039758) using the same plugin and it does not bring up the warning.

Can some please help me with this?

Asking users to turn of the mixed content warning in their IE9 is not an option.

Comment: you are likely calling the plugin or some of your content over SSL. You will get this warning in IE anytime you have "mixed content"

Comment: yes finally, someone on the page:-).both ref pages are http and my site too. The comments in facebook are httpS so there should be a "mixed content warning" in IE9 for all that I know. The question is, how has det publisher with ref in the question made it so that he can publish https facebook comments on a http site and dose not bring up the warning "show all content" in my IE9

Answer (score 1):

We were just looking at this today and our workaround for now was to include the Facebook Library over https (even when the page itself is viewed over http).  Although not ideal it gets rid of the mixed content warnings in IE9 until they have fixed their bug.

That seems to be how it was accomplished at www.vg.no linked in the original question, the library is linked via https.

From their code:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/nb_NO/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:

I have a page that's 100% http.  But, the facebook javascript (which I call over http), is returning assets (.js, images) over https, which is generating security warnings for IE(9) users.

I have figured out it's the comment widget from Facebook (

Here's an example of a live page on http: with the error:
    http://app.gophoto.com/p?id=10173&rkey=CD01891B287792415384&s=1&a=6940

Here's one of the assets that Facebook returns over HTTPS
    https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y8/r/7Htnnss1mJY.js

(I'm unable to comment (for some reason?) on Joel's answer.  But, his suggestion to fetch the initial all.js over https on http sites does not actually work. I've tried it, and it also inherently looks incorrect since even the initial js fetch violates the mixing up of http & https content.)

Comment: yes same on my http site and many others I have seen. So the big question is how can this publisher http://www.vg.no/teknologi/artikkel.php?artid=10039758 with the same plugin avoid it?